# How to provide custom Maneuver Icon in HERE Maps Android premium sdk?

Tags: android, navigation, maps, here-api

I need to provide my own arrow icons as mentioned in https://developer.here.com/documentation/android-premium/api_reference_java/com/here/android/mpa/routing/Maneuver.Icon.html
but I don't get a clue on how to do that.

I started navigation for calculated MapRoute with NavigationManager and got Maneuver object.Can someone help me how to add arrow icon in map. Thanks!

```
NavigationManager navigationManager = NavigationManager.getInstance();
            navigationManager.setMap(mMap);
            navigationManager.addNewInstructionEventListener(new WeakReference<>(new NavigationManager.NewInstructionEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onNewInstructionEvent() {
                    super.onNewInstructionEvent();
                    navigationManager.getNextManeuver();// Maneuver
                    // how to set icon to this maneuver??
                }
            }));

            navigationManager.startNavigation(mapRoute.getRoute());
```

Answer (score 2):

The Maneuver class in the HERE Mobile SDK contains an enum attribute called Icon.  The Icon contains a description of the maneuver but does not provide a visual representation. You can collect your own representation(images) and display it on the map based on the enum set.